# Missing script output in Elastic Beanstalk engine log?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, prisma, npm-scripts

I'm deploying a Node.js project on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The projects uses the Prisma ORM which has a postinstall script that [generates the client](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-prismaclient/generating-prisma-client). This script was failing for me because I didn't include the prisma folder in my deployment bundle so the schema lookup failed.

When I run `npm install` locally and the postinstall failes to find the schema I get the following output:

```
> @prisma/client@3.6.0 postinstall /<redacted>/node_modules/@prisma/client
> node scripts/postinstall.js

Environment variables loaded from .env
prisma:warn The postinstall script automatically ran `prisma generate` and did not find your `prisma/schema.prisma`.
If you have a Prisma schema file in a custom path, you will need to run
`prisma generate --schema=./path/to/your/schema.prisma` to generate Prisma Client.
If you do not have a Prisma schema file yet, you can ignore this message.
```

but when EB installed dependencies and the postinstall ran there was no such output in `eb-engine.log`:

```
> @nestjs/core@8.1.1 postinstall /var/app/staging/node_modules/@nestjs/core
> opencollective || exit 0


> @prisma/client@3.6.0 postinstall /var/app/staging/node_modules/@prisma/client
> node scripts/postinstall.js

added 114 packages from 89 contributors and audited 917 packages in 9.724s
```

I also tried looking through the other logs but couldn't find the warning text. Why is it not there?

Comment: Can you check `/var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log`?

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing relating to Prisma there. It's mostly alternating between a row of asterisks and `ConfigSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild`.